# How to make a Chatbot component using react-simple-chatbot in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, chat, chatbot

I am trying to make a React-Simple-Chatbot component in dynamic ReactJS,
using the [react-simple-chatbot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-chatbot) library.

What I am trying to do is to set the **message** property dynamically in the **steps** array.

Any suggestions on how to best do that would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ChatBot from "react-simple-chatbot";

function CustomChatbot(props) {

  const steps = [{
      id: "Greet",
      message: props.data,
      trigger: "Ask Name"
    },
    {
      id: "Ask Name",
      message: "Please type your name?",
      trigger: "Waiting user input for name"
    },
    {
      id: "Waiting user input for name",
      user: true,
      //trigger: "Asking options to eat"
      trigger: (input) => {
        props.eventHandler(input.value);
        return "Asking options to eat"
      }
    },
    {
      id: "Asking options to eat",
      message: "Hi {previousValue}, Please click on what you want to buy...?",
      trigger: "Displaying options to eat"
    },
    {
      id: "Displaying options to eat",
      options: [{
          value: "pizza",
          label: "Jeans",
          trigger: "Asking for Tomatoes in Pizza"
        },
        {
          value: "burger",
          label: "Jacket",
          trigger: "Burger Not available"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "Burger Not available",
      message: "Sorry, We don't have burger available at the moment. Would you like to try our pizza?",
      trigger: "Asking for pizza after burger"
    },
    {
      id: "Asking for pizza after burger",
      options: [{
          value: true,
          label: "Yes",
          trigger: "Asking for Tomatoes in Pizza"
        },
        {
          value: "false",
          label: "No",
          trigger: "Done"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

    return (<ChatBot steps={steps} {...config} />);
  }

  export default CustomChatbot;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const steps = [
   {
     id: "1",
     message: "Hello?",
     trigger: "query",
   },
   {
     id: "query",
     user: true,
     trigger: "3",
   },
   {
     id: "3",
     component: <CustomComponent />, // Mention Custom component here
     asMessage: true,
    trigger: "query",
   },   ];
   return (<ChatBot steps={steps} {...config} />);   }

 export default CustomChatbot;
```

//Custom Component

```
   export const CustomComponent = () =>{
   
   return( <div>Chat Bot Custom Component </div> )
   
   }
```